# SUM results is multiplying by number of rows

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, hana, sapb1

I'm creating a crystal report from several tables.

One table has fields that I want to have sum totals on, but these sum fields are being distorted by number of rows from another table. There are no fields other than `DocEntry` that I can link with between the two tables.

Here, total bales is repeating 4 times:

[image: Field duplicated]

If I sum the field total bales, instead of showing 12 the result is 48:

[image: wrong sum results]

Please assist.

Comment: Try to add Running Total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a Group on DocEntry.

Add a ***Running Total*** that sums Bales but evaluates only on change of group.